# Glutaraldehyde or Glutardialdehyde

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, carbonyl-compounds, chemical-formula

Recently I was searching for a chemical compound to meet my research needs, i.e. glutaraldehyde, and later I found that Merck has been released different name of compound: (1) glutaraldehyde and (2) glutardialdehyde, with the same CAS number, i.e. 111-30-8:

1. Many articles I've read, just mention glutaraldehyde, not glutardialdehyde.
2. Does glutardialdehyde and glutaraldehyde are the same compound?

Comment: if the Merck says they are the same and they have the same CAS number, they are the same. I have never heard it referred to as glutardialdehyde and I worked for the business unit that made it. Merck is just trying to be "inclusive".

Comment: IMO, glutaraldehtyde follows from glutaric acid, which is already difunctional. Glutardialdehyde appears to be redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Many articles I've read, just mention glutaraldehyde, not glutardialdehyde.

Not only Merck, but also Sigma-Aldrich listed [glutardialdehyde](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/mm/820603) (25% solution) and [glutaraldehyde](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/sial/g6257?gclid=CjwKCAjw1YCkBhAOEiwA5aN4ASexkqLdbDFVa5wSQ4EhACppwZqRV1mPRsieHk4K1YoMkgd4M4QzmxoC8RkQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) (25% solution) under the same CAS # (111-30-8). Surprisingly, glutaraldehyde is more expensive (USD 48.70/100 mL) than glutardialdehyde (USD 34.10/100 mL)! :-)

> Does glutardialdehyde and glutaraldehyde are the same compound?

Answer to this question is yes. However, the preferred name for the compound glutardialdehyde or glutaraldehyde (CAS #: 111-30-8) with the formula $\ce{OHC-(CH2)3-CHO}$ is pentanedial (Ref.1). Other names for the same compound included glutaraldehyde, glutardialdehyde, glutaric acid dialdehyde, glutaric aldehyde, glutaric dialdehyde, and 1,5-pentanedial ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glutaraldehyde)).

**References:**

1. *Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry : IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013* (Blue Book); Prepared by Henri A. Favre and Warren H. Powell; The Royal Society of Chemistry: Cambridge, United Kingdom, 2014, p. 907 (ISBN: 978-0-85404-182-4).